# Determine if Worksheet Exists in Workbook using the MS Graph API

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the KingswaySoft Premium OData source to query the MS Graph API. I need to filter it by a given workbook name, and ultimately get all the worksheets in the workbook so I can check if a worksheet with a specific name exists. I'm trying to build what the Graph API query will look like, figuring I *should* be able to work backwards into the KingswaySoft OData component.

I have built a query that runs, and part of it is hard-coded (I'm choosing the first item in the list), but when the query runs, it times out. I'm unsure if I'm going about it the right way and need to change my approach or if I'm headed in the right direction. Below is my query (obviously changed the company names and guids):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites('contoso.sharepoint.com%2Cxxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzz-wwww-aaaaaaaaaaaa%2Cvvvvvvvv-bbbb-cccc-dddd-abcdefghjikl')/lists('vvvvvvvv-bbbb-cccc-dddd-abcdefghjikl')/items/1/driveItem/workbook](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites(%27contoso.sharepoint.com%2Cxxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzz-wwww-aaaaaaaaaaaa%2Cvvvvvvvv-bbbb-cccc-dddd-abcdefghjikl%27)/lists(%27vvvvvvvv-bbbb-cccc-dddd-abcdefghjikl%27)/items/1/driveItem/workbook)

The error that gets returned is "We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long."

Any suggestions on how to revise the query to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The URL I have works correctly for another workbook I created with only two worksheets and a few cells populated with data. It immediately returns the JSON with the info about the worksheets.

I believe the problem is the original workbook I was attempting to read is a macro-heavy, xlsm file with external connections. After posting my question, it occurred to me that even when I attempt to open it in Excel (online or desktop), it can take upwards of a minute. But, for the test workbook I created with almost no data and two worksheets, the graph query runs fine and returns immediately.

So my problem is the workbook and the graph API timing out, which is a separate question.